# SharePoint SPServices autocomplete not working for a column

Tags: 2010, jquery, spservices

I have a working jQuery SPServices code for a column *Description* in a list. The problem is, that when I try to get the data from another column, *Project Item*, with the same code, nothing happens. Also, when I try to put the code for the both columns, the code does not work for any. Both columns are of *Single line of text* type. The code is following:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById('ctl00_m_g_b3f08547_27a4_484c_938a_f92864c47b7a_SPTextSlicerValueTextControl').title = 'Test';

        $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({ 
            sourceList: "Projects",
            sourceColumn: "Project Item",
            columnName: "Test",
            ignoreCase: true,
            numChars: 2,
            slideDownSpeed: 50,
            debug: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sourceColumn should be the internal name of the column, not the displayname.

You can get the internal name for a column by browsing to: List Settings > Edit Column and look at the QueryString.

Comment: Spent hours on this! Thank you very, very much!

Just in case anybody wonders, the internal column name is in the QueryString which can be seen in the page URL, Field=YourInternalColumnName.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should change the display name to internal name.

You can find the internal name:

1. Go to List Settings
2. Scroll down on page to Columns section
3. In the list of Columns, click on the column names
4. View the address bar of the browser and look for the querystring part:
5. Then look for the '&Field='

Comment: Thanks for your help, and this is the right answer too, Robert was just quicker.